# Проблемы с созданием и отправкой почты

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть код, которым я хочу отправлять почту через Outlook:

```
import win32com.client as win32

ol = win32.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

mail = ol.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'example@example.com'
mail.Subject = 'Test mail'
mail.Body = 'Hello!!!'

mail.Display()
mail.Send()
```

но новое письмо в Outlook так и не создаётся.

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вы забыли добавить адрес отправителя в свойство From. Вот пример кода:

```
import win32com.client as win32

ol = win32.client.Dispatch('Outlook.Application')

mail = ol.CreateItem(0)
mail.To = 'example@example.com'
mail.From = 'name@example.com'
mail.Subject = 'Test mail'
mail.Body = 'Hello!!!'

mail.Display()
mail.Send()
```

Еще возможно, проблема заключается в том, что Outlook не запущен или не установлен на вашем компьютере. Попробуйте запустить Outlook и повторите попытку.

Также, возможно, что у вас есть проблемы с библиотекой win32com. Попробуйте обновить ее или переустановите.